# common lisp help equivalent to help in python

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, read-eval-print-loop, slime

At a python interpreter, one can simply type `help("name")` to visit documentation for `name.`

1. What is the equivalent in a common-lisp REPL (I am using SBCL)?
2. Note that I am using SLIME in emacs 24.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that `c-h m` displays information about the current buffer modes and the available keyboard commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these:

```
(documentation #'cons 'function)
(documentation 'most-positive-fixnum 'variable)
(describe #'cons)
```

Slime also has a bunch of shortcuts for looking at things: `slime-describe-symbol`, `slime-inspect` (and if you have the hyperspec sitting around, `slime-documentation-lookup`) might all be useful.

Comment: Also, see [apropos](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apropo.htm).  It doesn't return documentation for a name, but it can help in finding the name in the first place.